# Excluding chapters from ToC in amsbook

Tags: table-of-contents, amsbook

I'm writing a book using the `amsbook` class, and I've included a page for acknowledgements using `\chapter*{}`, thinking it wouldn't show up in the ToC.

However, it does (and for some reason it's supposed to do so, according to the `amsbook` manual); so the question is, how do I get rid of it from the ToC?

Comment: As for the reason amsbook (and other ams classes) do this: The intended use of this class is a technical volume. The prototypical use of a starred chapter in a technical volume is an executive summary. The executive summary goes in the table of contents.

Answer (score 14):

The [amsmath FAQ](http://www.ams.org/faq?faq_id=238) has a solution. Here's a modification of it, in a complete example:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\gobblefour}[4]{}
\newcommand*{\SkipTocEntry}{\addtocontents{toc}{\gobblefour}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\SkipTocEntry\chapter*{Hidden chapter}
\chapter{Shown chapter}
\end{document}
```

Just place `\SkipTocEntry` before a TOC entry you would like to hide.

If you use `hyperref`, take one argument more:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\gobblefive}[5]{}
\newcommand*{\SkipTocEntry}{\addtocontents{toc}{\gobblefive}}
```

Comment: @Stefan Kottwitz: Also works for chapters without *, this is great!

Comment: The FAQ link is broken, but the example code still works!

Answer (score 5):

You can change the value of the `tocdepth` counter just before the particular sectional unit which must not show in the ToC and then restore the original value:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}}
\chapter*{Preface}
\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Renewal of `\addtocontents` to gobble it's arguments can also be used to remove its entry into the ToC:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
{\renewcommand{\addtocontents}[2]{}
\chapter*{Preface}}% Not included in ToC
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}% Included in ToC
\end{document}
```

Localization of the `\renewcommand` allows for it to work only within the group.

Comment: I like this solution, but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work correctly for subsections (using amsart): it prevents the subsection name from printing at all, not just in ToC. For sections it works fine. I'm using hyperref if it at all matters.