# Table of Contents without Appendix chapters in Latex

Tags: table-of-contents

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Excluding chapters from ToC in amsbook](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20543/excluding-chapters-from-toc-in-amsbook)

is it possible in LaTeX to have *numbered* chapters inside the appendix, without having them appear in the Table of Contents (TOC)?

Comment: You can use `{\renewcommand{\addtocontents}[2]{}
\chapter{Appendix chapter}}` to remove the appendix chapter from the ToC. Grouping the `\renewcommand` localizes the change.

Comment: It works but it doesn't show anything, neither the bibliography.
I'd like hiding all chapters of appendix, but showing both appendix (only one generic entry for the start of the appendix) and bibliography.

Comment: For a generic `Appendix` entry, insert `\addtocontents{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}`, followed by `\let\oldaddtocontents\addtocontents \renewcommand{\addtocontents}[2]{}` and then use your appendix chapters as usual. Then, before your `Bibliography`, add `\let\addtocontents\oldaddtocontents`. This assumes your document structure is such that you have a bibliography *following* you appendix. If this is not the case, you must have used the `\renewcommand` I suggested in the previous comment too soon.

Answer (score 0):

Using the tip described [on TeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20545/7144):

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}}
\chapter{Preface}
\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
```