# Elimination of individual elements in table of contents (TOC)

Tags: table-of-contents

Of course, one can include individual elements into a table of contents by inclusion of `addcontentsline` at the element to be included.  I'm seeking the opposite:  I want to *prevent* selected individual elements from appearing in the table of contents when they otherwise would be.

Note that changing the *depth* of element to be included will not work for my case.  I may want *some* subsections to appear in the table of contents and not others.  Changing the depth will permit or prevent *all* subsections from appearing in the table of contents.

Is there a command (e.g., `deletecontentsline`) that will allow me to selectively prevent individual items from otherwise appearing in the TOC?

For my case, there will be no problems with numbering.  In particular, I want subsections *just in one section* to not appear in the table of contents.  So, even though there is section 1, subsection 1.1, 1.2, etc., and section 2, subsection 2.1, 2.2, etc. I want my table of contents to have only 1, 1.1., 1.2, and 2.  (not 2.1, 2.2, etc.).

Comment: The package tocvsec2 will allow you reset the toc depth locally.

Comment: as an alternative, there's a technique used at the ams that lets you ignore an entry in the toc file.  the command, `\SkipTocEntry`, must be defined in the job itself, and how it is defined depends on whether or not `hyperref` is being used.  [full instructions here](http://www.ams.org/faq?faq_id=238).  (ulrike's suggestion is probably better if it works for you; it's certainly "more conventional".)

Comment: @barbarabeeton  Your solution was simple and worked perfectly.  Thanks so much.

Comment: there are several answered questions that cite this technique, so probably this should be treated as a duplicate: [Excluding chapters from ToC in amsbook](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20546/579).  (the technique isn't limited to use with ams document classes.)

Answer (score 0):

One way, with `etoc`. Works the same with or without `hyperref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoc}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

%\part{ONE}
\section{Section one}
\subsection{Subsection one one}
\subsection{Subsection one two}

\section{Section two}
\subsection{Subsection two one}
\subsection{Subsection two two}

\etocsettocdepth.toc {section}
\section{Section three DO NOT SHOW SUBSECTIONS}
\subsection{Subsection three one}
\subsection{Subsection three two}

\etocsettocdepth.toc {subsection}
\section{Section four}
\subsection{Subsection four one}
\subsection{Subsection four two}

\end{document}
```

[image: TOC with etoc]