# Remove acknowledgments from the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm writing my thesis. I would like to insert the acknowledgments after the frontispiece and before the table of contents.

I write

```
\chapter*{Acknowledgments}

....

\thispagestyle{empty}
```

But the problem is that it appear in the table of contents and I don't want it. How can I do to exclude this chapter from the table of contents?

Comment: Add `\clear(double)page` before `\printindex`?

Comment: @Bernard I don't use the command \printindex but only \tableofcontents...

Comment: Do you mean the “table of contents”? In the standard classes, `\chapter*{...}` does not insert an entry in the table of contents, so an example is needed. What document class are you using?

Comment: @Bernard Yes I mean table of contents. I'm using "amsbook" and I would like to write the acknowledgments before it. My problem is that this appear in t.o.c. and i don't know how to hide it. I try to follow this post http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20543/excluding-chapters-from-toc-in-amsbook but it doesn't work..

Comment: @andreassvr: Initially, I read ‘the index’, whence my suggestion. Seemed weird, though. I don't know the details of `amsbook`, but try, before the acknowledgments, `\setcounter{tocnumdepth}{-1}`, and put the whole in a group.

Comment: @Bernard: Recall that the `\setcounter` command changes the value of a counter *globally*.

Comment: @andreasvr: Why didn’t the answers to [Excluding chapters from ToC in amsbook](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20543/69818) work?

Comment: @Gustavo Mezzetti: Do you mean, the O.P. should restore the default value afterwards? I suggested  to enclose the whole in a group mainly because I don't know the value for `amsbook`.

Comment: @Bernard: That is precisely *the* problem with the `tocnumdepth` approach: you need to restore the value manually, and the only completely reliable means of doing this is to store the current value in another counter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, the `amsbook` class defines `\chapter*` in such a way that an entry is added to the ToC.  You need to define a special command “by hand”:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\notocchapter[1]{%
  \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
  \thispagestyle{empty}\global\@topnum\z@
  \@afterindenttrue
  \let\@secnumber\@empty
  \@makeschapterhead{#1}\@afterheading
}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\notocchapter{Acknowledgments}
Thanks to everybody!

\chapter*{Introduction}
Introductory text.

\chapter{Genesis}
In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth.

\chapter{Exodus}
These are the names of the sons of Israel who went to Egypt with Jacob.

\end{document}
```

**Edit:** I’ve noticed that you want the `empty` page style on the acknowledgment page, so I’ve updated the above code accordingly.